# How can I mount a Windows folder and enforce its NTFS permissions?

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, kerberos

I have an existing Ubuntu server. Users already sign into it with AD credentials. The problem is that there is a mounted file share - in a Windows environment, the users only have access to folders they have permission for. On the Ubuntu server, the folder is accessed with a shared generic account, the credentials for that being stored in a hidden file in /etc/smbmounts. I'm tasked with making it so that the folders are accessed with the same AD credentials that the user used to login to the computer in the first place. That's a summary of the problem, the specifics below:

Here's the setup:

/etc/krb5.conf looks like this:

```
[libdefaults]

default_realm = DOMAIN.NAME

ticket_lifetime = 24h #

renew_lifetime = 7d
```

/etc/samba/smb.conf looks like this:

```
[global]

workgroup = DOMAIN

client signing = yes

client use spnego = yes

kerberos method = secrets and keytab

realm = DOMAIN.NAME

security = ads

server signing = mandatory
```

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]

domains = DOMAIN.name

config_file_version = 2

services = nss, pam

debug_level = 5

[domain/DOMAIN.name]

ad_domain = DOMAIN.name

krb5_realm = DOMAIN.NAME

realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli

cache_credentials = True

id_provider = ad

krb5_store_password_if_offline = True

default_shell = /bin/bash

ldap_id_mapping = True

use_fully_qualified_names = False

fallback_homedir = /home/domain/%u

#access_provider = ad

#ad_access_filter = (memberOf=cn=Linux Login Allowed,ou=Domain Groups,dc=Domain,dc=local

access_provider = simple

simple_allow_users = administrator

simple_allow_groups = Domain Admins, Linux Login Allowed

enumerate = true
```

For sssd permissions:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

sudo chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

Join to the domain:

```
sudo kinit [insert domain admin username here]

sudo klist

sudo net ads join –k
```

We've been using PAM for the Windows folder mounting:

```
<debug enable="0" />

<!-- Volume definitions -->

<volume sgrp="Linux Login Allowed" fstype="cifs" server="fileshare" path="files/userdata/%(USER)/Documents/linux_home" mountpoint="/home/DOMAIN/%(USER)" options="dir_mode=0700,sec=ntlm"/>

<!-- pam_mount parameters: General tunables -->

<logout wait="5000" hup="1" term="2" kill="3" />
```

/etc/fstab:

```
//fileshare/folder /folder cifs credentials=/etc/smbmounts/.folder,gid=1003,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I included everything I could think of pertaining to this setup for full disclosure, but to be clear the problem is not with PAM home folder mounting. It's with the fstab - that //fileshare/folder is the shared folder with NTFS permissions that is vexing me.

I think it would be preferable if I did not upend the existing setup much for folder permissions.

Ideally, I'd like to change the fstab to look for credentials from the initial Samba/SSSD/Kerberos setup for AD authentication and login, rather than the smbmounts file that contains a shared username/password. If possible, a single sign on. Can it be this simple, and if so, what change needs to be made?

I appreciate any help, still fairly new to Linux in general.

Let me know if anymore information needs to be added/removed to make this topic more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, everyone! I found the answer at this link, the best answer post: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/484483-mounting-windows-shares-on-lubuntu

PBIS was not required to join to the domain or get authentication, it worked without it.